# Why is Airflow not seeing it's HOME folder?

Tags: linux, docker, airflow

I'm setting up an Airflow instance but for some reason Airflow is not seeing it's `$AIRFLOW_HOME` folder.

The setup is using the [official Airflow image (2.6.1/py3.8)](https://hub.docker.com/layers/apache/airflow/2.6.1-python3.8/images/sha256-0fc7b4fff2582bf0f5d454492f04fecd7c6293ae0d4feb8bccc753ff9a2281ef?context=explore) with the default $AIRFLOW_HOME being `/opt/airflow/`. I mounted a local folder `- ./files:/opt/airflow/files` but for some reason this isn't working as inteded and Airflow is not running the tasks from this folder.

Using a BashOperator i can get this task to run:

`bash_command='cd /opt/airflow/files/my-repo/ && python taskpy'`

But not this one:

`bash_command=' python files/my-repo/task.py'`

I was under the impresion that anything added to the $AIRFLOW_HOME folder would be mapped by Airflow and could be used right away. Is this wrong?

Something strange that i've noticed is that when i try to access this env variable ($AIRFLOW_HOME) from the airflow user i get a Permission denied error:

```
(airflow)$AIRFLOW_HOME
/bin/sh: 1: /opt/airflow: Permission denied
```

Is there anything i'm missing?

Comment: Have you set AIrFLOW_UID? echo -e "AIRFLOW_UID=$(id -u)" > .env

Answer (score 1):

If executing the command `echo $AIRFLOW_HOME` does not display any output, it means that the environment variable `AIRFLOW_HOME` is either not set or is set to an empty value.

To set the `AIRFLOW_HOME` variable, you can do one of the following:

1. Set it explicitly in the terminal:

   ```bash
   export AIRFLOW_HOME=/path/to/airflow/home
   ```

   Replace `/path/to/airflow/home` with the actual path where you want to set your Airflow home directory.
2. Add the `export` command to your shell configuration file (e.g., `~/.bashrc` for Bash) to make it persist across sessions:

   ```bash
   echo "export AIRFLOW_HOME=/path/to/airflow/home" >> ~/.bashrc
   source ~/.bashrc
   ```

   Again, replace `/path/to/airflow/home` with the desired path.

After setting the `AIRFLOW_HOME` variable, you can verify if it is properly configured by running `echo $AIRFLOW_HOME` again. It should display the path you assigned to it. Remember to restart your terminal or source the configuration file if you modified it in step 2 for the changes to take effect.